# Android. Create app direct access

Tags: android, homescreen

I've observed that in some cases, when yo install an app (for example shazam) a direct access it's automatically created in the home screen.

I want to export this behaviour to my developed apps.

Does someone know how it could be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating shortcut on the home screen through application on install is not possible.
There is optional settings in Play Store App to auto create shortcut on install.

Alternatively,you can use below code to create shortcut in OnCreate method of MainActivity:

Require Manifest Permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Use below code to programmatically create shortcut.

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent();
shortcutIntent.setClassName("<Your app package>", "Class Name");
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Create shortcut itself

```
Intent addSCIntent = new Intent();
addSCIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
addSCIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "<Shortcut Name>");
addSCIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
addSCIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
context.sendBroadcast(addSCIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean adding a shortcut to the homescreen. This [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-install-uninstall-shortcut-example/) will help you.